# Ability to remove action overrides in Lightning whilst leaving them in place in Classic

Tags: lightning-experience, migration, button-overrides

The documentation states/strongly implies that there should be an ability to leave an action override in place in Salesforce Classic, whilst removing it in Lightning/Mobile:

[Remove Overrides for Standard Buttons and Tab Home Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_customize_override_remove.htm&type=5)

However, step 3 describes options which not available within our org:

> Select No override (default behavior) for the experience whose override you want to remove (Salesforce Classic, Lightning Experience, or mobile).

[image: Available options on Override screen]

We've had a case open with Salesforce for a few weeks now and I can't seem to make any headway (they say the documentation team say that their documentation is correct, but also can't explain why I don't see the options that the documentation says should be there)

Being able to switch off the override in LEX would be ideal. As we're in Lightning Console, using Lightning Components to override the override behaviour specifically for LEX still results in unwanted behaviours (tabs being opened unnecessarily, no access to inline editing, etc.) The only option remaining to us may be to have to re-build an object model specifically for LEX, which I'm sure isn't the desired approach when migrating to LEX

Is anybody able to confirm which is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I can confirm I also can't switch off the override for LEX in my organizations

Comment: I would suggest to push harder on Salesforce Support and escalate the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product owner of this area contacted me and this was a documentation issue. The functionality doesn't exist (there are ideas requesting it), so the documentation will hopefully be improved to make this clearer.

In the meantime, Idea is here:

[Allow "No override (use default)" for button overrides for Lightning Experience](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CUtAQAW)