# How to remove Classic override for object Tab without bothering Lightning users?

Tags: lightning-experience, tab, salesforce-classic, page-override

In Classic we used to have Visualforce page overrides for the Account, Lead, Case, ... tabs.

Now that all our users have migrated to Lightning, we want to remove all Visualforce pages. The first step is to remove the Override for Standard Tab Home Pages. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.links_customize_override_remove.htm&type=5) is the documentation on how to do that.

When you actually do this, you will notice that you must select the "Use the Salesforce Classic override" option for Lightning. You cannot select nothing. For Classic, this just works. But in Lightning, when you go to, let's say, the Opportunities tab, you get a Lightning version of the Classic Opportunities tab. It looks weird:

[image]

The only way to get the Lightning Tab view back (we have never used tab overrides in Lightning), is to refresh via Ctrl-F5. I have tried several other methods, including completely closing the browser, but that was never enough. I always had to refresh via Ctrl-F5 to get the Lightning view.

I do not want to "surprise" the users with this experience, I would not like them to contact our support department about this, and I really would not like to send a mail to all users telling them to press Ctrl-F5 when they see strange screens.

Is there a way to make this transition less awkward?

UPDATE: I see a [related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261912/ability-to-remove-action-overrides-in-lightning-whilst-leaving-them-in-place-in?rq=1), and the strange thing is: all standard object tabs were overridden in Classic by Visualforce pages and for all these tabs, the Lightning setting already was: "Use the Salesforce Classic override"

But that is not what we saw in Lightning, we always got the standard Lightning tab views. Until I reset the Classic setting to "Standard" and all of a sudden we see Classic views in Lightning :-(

Comment: Not sure if you can verify - but, It seems to only occur with the persistent and secure caching setting on? I tried to reproduce it in a dev org and couldn't - until I turned on `Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance`. That, obviously, might not be an option for you in production to turn off - but, if you have a support case might be helpful for reproduction steps.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves That setting is indeed turned on in our production org. I will experiment with it, in a sandbox.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I created a new sandbox, disabled that particular caching setting and then opted for "No override" for the Accounts tab page. I selected the Accounts tab immediately afterwards and I saw: the same Lightning+Classic screen as shown above in my question. So maybe some other setting in our org affects this.

Comment: I think we tested differently. I think if you now, with the cache off, re-do everything again (add override, click tab, remove override, click tab) - you'll see it much smoother to remove (no classic in lightning)?